# HP PageWide Pro MFP 477dw does not obtain IP address over Ethernet

Tags: networking, printer, hp

Having an **HP PageWide Pro MFP 477dw**, that was freshly reset, it **does not get an IP address** when started.

As told at page 33 of the manual, I conntected the printer through cable, powered it on and waited 60 seconds: https://www.modesdemploi.fr/hp/pagewide-pro-477dw/mode-d-emploi?p=33

**In the network settings, the value for the "IP Address" field remains: "Not connected".**
Other empty fields are "Subnetwork mask", "Default gateway" and "DNS Server".
The printer simply doesn't obtain any IP address.

I also deactivated the 802.11 wireless connection, and attempted restoring default network settings, shut the printer down and started it again. Still no IP.

The cable is correctly plugged and connects a simple Zyxel switch.
I can confirm that the Internet connection is working.

I also attempted a full reset of the printer.
For the wired network, the printer was telling that no cable was connected.

Are there known network issues for this model, either hardware or software ?
Is there a firmware update to apply?

---

**Edit #1**

[image: Schema of HP PageWide Pro MFP 477dw not getting IP]

- The room has two available RJ45 Ethernet sockets giving access to Internet through the router.
- The Ethernet switch is connected to one of the RJ45 sockets.
- The computer has access to Internet through wired connection the switch.
- The computer can print on network printers 1 and 2 through wired network connection, and also scan documents from printer one which is multifuntion.
- The third network printer (HP PageWide Pro MFP 477dw) does not get an IP address when wired (even if powered on after the wiring), and even if the wireless was disabled in the printer settings.

---

**Edit #2**

I printed the network report.
Here's what it tells, as translated to English, with some chars replaced  or masked:

```
General informations

      Network status                        offline
      Active connection                     none
      URL for integrated web server         http://0.0.0.0
      Firmware version                      MAVEDWPP1N001.2228B.00
      Host name                             HP*****D
      Serial number                         CN********
      Internet                              Not applicable

802.3 wired
  Hardware address (MAC)                fd:3e:dc:ae:**:**
  Link config.                          10TX - Half

Wireless 802.11
  Hardware address (MAC)                fd:3e:da:b8:**:**
  Status                                Disconnected
  Communication mode:                   infrastructure
  Network name (SSID)                   Not defined

Wi-Fi Direct
  Status                                Disabled
  Hadware address (MAC)                 fd:3e:da:b8:**:**

PORT 9100
  Status                                Enabled

...
```

---

**Edit #3**

- Printer can be installed with wireless connection.
- USB connection also working, even the printer was initially connected in wireless.
- **Ethernet connection still not working**, even if setting IP, network mask and gateway manually.
- Wireless configuration somewhat tricky. After powering the printer off, and on again, despite WiFi connection, printer was not reachable and had to be removed and added again in the list of peripheral devices.

Hardware issue assumed (or possibly a software bug).
I will stay with USB and WiFi unless a solution can be found.

Comment: You have tried a different networking cable?

Comment: Your setup is unclear. Perhaps a graphical schema will help, with emphasis on where is the router which is the DHCP server in your local network. Does the printer work if you connect it via ethernet cable to the computer?

Comment: Have you connected another device to the same cable to make sure that is working and the other device gets an IP?

Comment: @Ramhound: Yes, I tried several different networking cables that are successfuly used on a daily basis.

Comment: @harrymc: I added a graphical schema and comments below. 
No, the printer does not work if I connect is via Ethernet cable directly to the computer. As far as I know, a computer is not a router and has not the role of attributing IP adresses. The benefit of a network printer is to be sharable among different computers. Else, I would use USB connection.

Comment: @music2myear: Yes, connected the same cable to another network printer and can confirm that the other it worked like a charm.

Comment: I think having a clue about where the problem is coming from: I observe that after start, the computer is always tring to establishing a wireless connection (Wi-Fi is on). I disabled the Wi-Fi in the settings, but it always come again when the printer is started. Hence, I assume the printer does not ask for an Ethernet IP address, as attempting to get one through wireless. I have no idea how to disable Wi-Fi and make the printer memorize it when starting next time.

Comment: “No, the printer does not work if I connect is via Ethernet cable directly to the computer.” - Your supposed to connect the printer directly to the computer with a USB cable not Ethernet. Your computer using WiFi isn’t the problem unless your wireless network isn’t the same subnet as your Ethernet subnet. If the same router is handling both they should be the same.

Comment: @Ramound: I agree that for a direct connection from a unique computer, USB is the way to go. WiFi is disabled on the computer (there is a physical switch for this on my laptop). I still believe that the problem comes from the printer attempting a Wifi attempt : my assumption is that the printer is trying to get IP from a WiFi connection, it renounces trying to get IP from the Ethernet port. In other words, as regarding networking, the printer would be monontask (with wireless first), as opposite to multitask (competing attempts on wired and wireless to get an IP).

Comment: I added the content of the printer network report.

Comment: Ramhound, are you suggesting that as a workaround? @OuzoPower yes, networking is the better way to share a printer, however, this printer seems have an issue with its firmware/settings and/or network hardware. It should remember your settings across a power cycle, however, you also don't typically turn a printer off and on, you just leave it on all the time. This is normal for many electronics. After turning WiFi off, does the ethernet work? If the printer is new and under warranty, I would contact support for service.

Comment: @music2myear - I am not suggesting that as a workaround.  I am suggesting that connecting the printer to the Ethernet port of a machine won't work since the printer does not have an IP Address.  However, by connecting the printer to the computer over USB you can configure it using the HP Smart application on Windows. The IP address in the networking configuration page explains the reason it cannot be mapped.

Comment: @music2myear: Yes, this printer seems having an issue, either with network hardware or firmware. I typically turn printer on and off daily and few times (e.g. morning and afternoon), and only when I need to print. I am preparing it for an event. The Ethernet does not work after turning WiFi off. According to the manual, this printer should get its Ethernet IP address when it is started. The printer is second hand, but apart this problem in excellent condition.

Comment: @Ramound: Thank you for mentioning HP Smart. I was also considering installing it but I am usually reticent adding such softwares as they are often not much more than bloatwares.